# Using ‘later’ when the amount of time is a complex phrase

Tags: phrases, adverbs, time

In sentences like ‘The speed 10 seconds later is 3 m/s’ the amount of time is easy to specify. But what can I do if it is a complex phrase? In particular, I should like to express *v*(*t* + d*t*) in words, where *v* is speed, *t* is an instant and *t* + d*t* is a later instant in which d*t* reads ‘the amount of time it takes for the picket fence to travel 5 cm’. I cannot just squeeze this phrase in front of ‘later’, can I? Is there a phrase like ‘later BY an amount of time’?

Thank you in advance for any useful tip.

Comment: Simply say "This will happen at a certain time later, as given by the mathematical expression ....."  OK?

Comment: Thank you very much, but unfortunately I cannot use it as my aim is to resolve a mathematical expression in words. Otherwise I could just say ‘dt later, where dt is given by...’. I wanted to avoid introducing a symbol solely for this purpose.

Comment: i would probably encourage you to ask on the math stackexchange site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *after*:

> The speed after the time it takes the picket fence to travel 5 cm is 3 m/s.